# What requires an I-864, "Affidavit of Support"?

Tags: usa, immigration

There form called an I-864 *"Affidavit of Support Under [Section 213A of the INA](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/part-213a)"* But, what requires this affidavit?

Is it needed when filing an I-130 or I-485? I see different mentions of this form in different places? Under what condition does one need an "Affidavit of Support"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. I-864 is not required for the I-130 itself.

- If you are doing Consular Processing (the process of getting a green card from outside the US), the NVC will ask for the I-864 from the petitioner during the Consular Processing process, which happens after the I-130 has been approved and a visa number is close to being available.
- If you are doing Adjustment of Status (the process of getting a green card from within the US), you must file I-864 with the I-485 form for Adjustment of Status.

Comment: Really good answer. Thanks!